# How to change a div without impacting nested div default size?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm creating a web application with angularjs and I need your help for a css issue.
I have several nested `div`. I want one of these nested `div` (which I'll call "myDiv" in the explication) to fill all the screen.
But this configuration for "myDiv" shouldn't affect his nested child `div`. 
Here a very simple example of the situation :

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div class="myDiv">
         ...
         <div>
            ...
            <div>...</div>
            ...
         </div>
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

"..." means random content. 
By default `div` inside "myDiv" will have default width/height. (I didn't put any css for them so these values for width/height will be decided by the size of the parent "myDiv")
I want these default values to be exactly the same but I want "myDiv" to fill all the screen. 
Just like a padding but without changing the display in the screen so not a padding.

Do you have an idea to do that only with CSS or with angularjs ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Will this selected div need to be **actually** wider than the others or is this just to add a 100% wide background or something.

Comment: I tried to modify CSS of all parent `div` of "myDiv" in different ways (%, px, % and px). The thing is instead of changing parent `div` css, I have no idea how to do it. I also search on several forum a possible solution. I found a lot of topics about this but not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Paulie_D, a width of 100% will automaticly change the size of the child div and the display. In fact "myDiv" will be used to unselect an item when the user click on this div. "myDiv" has a specific controller so I cant put the unselect event on a higher div. And I want the unselect event to be triggered at any place of the screen so I need "myDiv" to take all the screen"

Comment: Only using CSS I think that is not possible. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Mtoypc That's not what I'm asking. Does it actually need to be 100% width of the browser (that is **content** will stretch from side to side**) or is it just a visual effect?

Comment: Is it ok for `myDiv` to hide the contents of it's parents ?

Comment: Yes "myDiv" can hide his parent content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
`<div>
 <div>
 <div class="myDiv">
 <div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting       industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
      <div><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>`
```

with css

```
div.myDiv{
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
bottom:0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

Using Position Absolute will remove the div from flow of the document and you can size it to fill the whole viewport.

Comment: With the two solutions you gave me, I pass from :  [before](http://hpics.li/a1bb93a) to [after](http://hpics.li/e6e39a3). It's difficult to see the difference between the two images but when we pass from one to the other we can see that the second is a bit more larger than the first (only look the width for these pictures the height is good).

Answer (score 0):

Check this `position: absolute or fixed` can help

```css
.myDiv{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
      Some content here - This text will be hidden
      <div class="myDiv">
         ...
         <div>
            ...
            <div>...</div>
            ...
         </div>
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. The content size inside "myDiv" change. (The content of the first nested `div` take more place in the screen than before)